# split and cut string in Makefile

Tags: shell, awk, sed, makefile, cut

I'm working on a Makefile.

```
version := v39.0.12.8    // format rules: va.b.c.d
```

I want to get "version_a" based on the format, which is "39" in this case. 
How to do this?  Maybe via "sed/cut/awk but I'm not familar with these shell command.

e.g.

```
version         version_a  version_b   version_c  version_d
v39.0.12.8      39         0            12        8
v87.2.9.17      87         2            9         17
v142.98.77.68   142        98           77        68
```

Comment: This might help with GNU make: [Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions)

Answer (score 8):

This can be achieved with `make` functionality, like so:

```
$ cat Makefile
version := v39.0.12.8

version_tuple := $(subst ., ,$(version:v%=%))

version_a := $(word 1,$(version_tuple))
version_b := $(word 2,$(version_tuple))
version_c := $(word 3,$(version_tuple))
version_d := $(word 4,$(version_tuple))

all:
        echo version_tuple = $(version_tuple)
        echo version_a = $(version_a)
        echo version_b = $(version_b)
        echo version_c = $(version_c)
        echo version_d = $(version_d)
```

Output:

```
$ make -s
version_tuple = 39 0 12 8
version_a = 39
version_b = 0
version_c = 12
version_d = 8
```

Answer (score 2):

With [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) you can execute a [glob match](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt#call-glob-matchstringpattern) on your version number:

```
include gmtt/gmtt.mk

version := v39.0.12.8

matchresult := $(call glob-match,$(version),v*.*.*.*)

$(info [$(matchresult)])

major := $(word 2,$(matchresult))
minor := $(word 4,$(matchresult))
bugfix := $(word 6,$(matchresult))
buildcnt := $(word 8,$(matchresult))

$(info Major = $(major))
$(info Minor = $(minor))
$(info Bugfix = $(bugfix))
$(info Buildcnt = $(buildcnt))

$(if $(call int-ge,$(major),39),$(info Major is 39 or higher!))
```

Answer (score 0):

*As an alternative to the other great answers, here is my preferred solution.*

Makefile:

```
split-dot = $(word $2,$(subst ., ,$1))

version := v39.0.12.8
version_a := $(call split-dot,$(version:v%=%),1)
version_b := $(call split-dot,$(version),2)
version_c := $(call split-dot,$(version),3)
version_d := $(call split-dot,$(version),4)

all:
    $(info version_a=$(version_a))
    $(info version_b=$(version_b))
    $(info version_b=$(version_c))
    $(info version_b=$(version_d))
```

output:

```
$ make -s
version_a=39
version_b=0
version_b=12
version_b=8
```